# "Create" Action Method Not Working ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

When I add the following lines to the Tournament class the `Create` action method doesn't work in the webapp It just reloads the page. I recorded a short clip to show what it does: https://youtu.be/pvanpQD8LhM. I am using .NET 7

Code causing the problem:

```
        public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
```

Here's the classes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Tournament
    {
     
        public int TournamentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TournamentName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        //public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        //public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
        
    }
}



namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        //public DateTime GameDate { get; set; }
        public string Player1 { get; set; }
        public string Player2 { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }

        
        public int TournamentId { get; set; }
        public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I first tried different code from a Tutorial, which didn't work. I got this from the EFTutorial website. I have also tried removing the required annotations.

Edit:

Here's the create action method for Tournament:

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Tournament/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TournamentId,TournamentName,Location")] Tournament tournament)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(tournament);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(tournament);
        }
```

Here's the create action method for Game:

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["TournamentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Tournament, "TournamentId", "TournamentId");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Game/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("GameId,Player1,Player2,Score,TournamentId")] Game game)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(game);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["TournamentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Tournament, "TournamentId", "TournamentId", game.TournamentId);
            return View(game);
        }
```

Comment: How exactly it "didn't work"?

Comment: @GuruStron No it's not currently working

Comment: @GuruStron When I click the create button it just reloads the page. You can see it in the video https://youtu.be/pvanpQD8LhM.

Comment: @TJ_Frags Could you please show your Create Action method in  your controller.

Comment: @Manik I added it to the post

Comment: Sorry ,  the youtube link you provided is not show anything , I can't check the view code, Can you provide your view code? Both Tournament and game create action can't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description in this post, I think every time you create `Tournament` model in `HttpPost` create action, `ModelState.IsValid` is false and you will run `return View(tournament)` then the page will reload and show `The Games field is required.` error message in your view, right?

The reason is Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the enable element in the project file. It means the project will add [requried] attribute by default even if you don't add it manually. So when you create `Tournament` model. The `Games` field is null, So  `ModelState.IsValid` will be false and return `The Games field is required.` error message. You can just  add `?` to make this field nullable.

```
public ICollection<Game>? Games { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

@TJ_Frags you might want to try and just simply redirect to index in your create method. If that works then you need to debug your code from `if (ModelState.IsValid)` onwards. My guess is your `RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));` is not reachable as `public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }` might be invalidating model state.

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Tournament/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TournamentId,TournamentName,Location")] Tournament tournament)
    {
       
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to reply. I had load shedding. Your right. I used the following code in the Create.cshtml: 

`
<div syle="color:red">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>

`
It showed this: "The Games field is required."

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @TJ_Frags you can simply declare it as null with ? as explained by Xinran Shen above